# Resolve environment variables of property file Java ResourceBundle

Tags: java, spring, java-8, properties

Our application is using java8 and spring. We are working to moving to kubernetes. For that reason, I want to use environment variables in the `properties` file like as follow and declare the -

```
conf.dir.path = ${APPLICATION_CONF_PATH}
database.name = ${APPLICATION_DB_SCHEMA}
save.file.path = ${COMMON_SAVE_PATH}${APPLICATION_SAVE_PATH}
# And many more keys
```

But right now the values are not resolved/expanded by environment variable.

Application initialization of property is as below -

```
public enum ApplicationResource {
    CONF_DIR_PATH("conf.dir.path"),
    DB_NAME("database.name")
    FILE_SAVE_PATH("save.file.path"),
    // And many more keys

    private final String value;

    ApplicationResource(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    private static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "ApplicationResource";
    private static Properties props;

    static {
        try {
            Properties defaults = new Properties();
            initEnvironment(defaults, BUNDLE_NAME);
            props = new Properties(defaults);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void initEnvironment(Properties props, String bundleName) throws Throwable {
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle(bundleName);
        Enumeration<?> enu = rb.getKeys();
        String key = null;
        String value = null;
        while (enu.hasMoreElements()) {
            key = (String) enu.nextElement();
            value = rb.getString(key);
            props.setProperty(key, value);
        }
    }

    public String getString() {
        return props.getProperty(value);
    }

    public int getInt() throws NumberFormatException {
        String str = getString();
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return Integer.parseInt(str);
        }
    }
}
```

`getString` is used extensively. Right now when `getString` is called, it returns the literal string from the properties file. Is there any way to properly resolve environment variables without impacting the codebase?

**Edit**: By [without impacting the codebase], I meant only changing/editing code in the above enum/class file and the change being transparent in other areas.

Comment: How do you pass environment variables to the spring boot application?

Comment: You mean how do I set the environment variables? It will be through kubernetes configmap.

Comment: The short answer no you will need to modify the code base to make it work. I also wonder why you are even doing this at all instead of just loading those files as `@PropertySource` and use `@Value` (or typed configs) to resolve them.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you. What do you think about making a function like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752817/expand-environment-variables-in-text) and call the function in the `value = rb.getString(key)` line?

Comment: Which would mean modifying the code, which you stated you didn't want to do.

Comment: Very sorry, I meant not changing the code where the properties are accessed in other areas/files like `domain.setDbName(ApplicationResource.DB_NAME.getString())`. If the code change is contained in the class above, and the change is transparent in other areas then that will be the best solution.

Comment: "Our application is using java8 and spring. We are working to moving to kubernetes" => spring-cloud-kubernetes. Reading properties via configmaps/secrets is going to be very easy and dealing with ENV variables too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest variant based on the Regex engine would be:

```java
private static final Pattern VARIABLE = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(.*?)\\}");
```

```java
public String getString() {
    return VARIABLE.matcher(props.getProperty(value))
        .replaceAll(mr -> Matcher.quoteReplacement(System.getenv(mr.group(1))));
}
```

This replaces all occurrences of `${VAR}` with the result of looking up `System.getenv("VAR")`. If the string contains no variable references, the original string is returned. It does, however, not handle absent variables. If you want to handle them (in a different way than failing with a runtime exception), you have to add the policy to the function.

E.g. the following code keeps variable references in their original form if the variable has not been found:

```java
public String getString() {
    return VARIABLE.matcher(props.getProperty(value))
        .replaceAll(mr -> {
            String envVal = System.getenv(mr.group(1));
            return Matcher.quoteReplacement(envVal != null? envVal: mr.group());
        });
}
```

`replaceAll(Function<MatchResult, String>)` requires Java 9 or newer. For previous versions, you’d have to implement such a replacement loop yourself. E.g.

```java
public String getString() {
    String string = props.getProperty(value);
    Matcher m = VARIABLE.matcher(string);
    if(!m.find()) return string;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int last = 0;
    do {
        String replacement = System.getenv(m.group(1));
        if(replacement != null) {
            sb.append(string, last, m.start()).append(replacement);
            last = m.end();
        }
    } while(m.find());
    return sb.append(string, last, string.length()).toString();
}
```

This variant does not use `appendReplacement`/`appendTail` which is normally used to build such loops, for two reasons.

- First, it provides more control over how the replacement is inserted, i.e. by inserting it literally via `append(replacement)` we don’t need `Matcher.quoteReplacement(…)`.
- Second, we can use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer` which might also be more efficient. The Java 9 solution uses `StringBuilder` under the hood, as support for it has been added to `appendReplacement`/`appendTail` in this version too. But for previous versions, `StringBuilder` can only be used when implementing the logic manually.

Note that unlike the `replaceAll` variant, the case of absent variables can be handled simpler and more efficient with a manual replacement loop, as we can simply skip them.

---

You said you don’t want to change the initialization code, but I still recommend bringing it into a more idiomatic form, i.e.

```java
private static void initEnvironment(Properties props, String bundleName) {
    ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle(bundleName);
    for(Enumeration<String> enu = rb.getKeys(); enu.hasMoreElements(); ) {
        String key = enu.nextElement();
        String value = rb.getString(key);
        props.setProperty(key, value);
    }
}
```

In the end, it’s still doing the same. But iteration loops should be using `for`, to keep initialization expression, loop condition and fetching the next element as close as possible. Further, there is no reason to use `Enumeration<?>` with a type cast when you can use `Enumeration<String>` in the first place. And don’t declare variables outside the necessary scope. And there’s no reason to pre-initialize them with `null`.

Comment: Thank you! By the way, do you recommend on changing the initialization code to something like spring propertysource? Is it possible to refactor this class?
Also, Will the regex `\\$\\{([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\\}` be better for finding environment variables?

Comment: `\\$\\{([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\\}` will be more restrictive regarding what is allowed between the curly braces. Considering that you most likely don’t have any other uses for `${…}` in property values, it doesn’t make a difference. Regarding the initialization… is there an actual reason why you copy the `ResourceBundle` into a `Properties` instance instead of just using the `ResourceBundle` directly?

Comment: IMO there is no reason. The codebase is quite old, about 8 years. I think nobody updated this part of code  because, it was working and there was no reason to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Spring support environment variable or system variable or application.property file
if you able to use kubernates configmap its better choice.
[How to set environment variable dynamically in spring test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46304932/how-to-set-environment-variable-dynamically-in-spring-test)

Comment: Goal is not to change the current initialization code. I want thinking about some variable resolving code in the `value = rb.getString(key)` line. If you have any recommendation with least amount of code I would love to know.